# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'firstname' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`) values (test@test.com))

Tags: php, laravel, crud, database-migration, laravel-controller

I am new to Laravel framework.

I am facing an issue, with migration of User table.I added nullable to 'firstname' of my table, which works but displaying the same error for 'lastname'column. I have included nullable() to every column, which is not the right way to do it. How to solve this?? Can anyone please suggest.

User migration table, facing issue with the 'firstname' column.
**create_user_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->char('address',100);
        $table->bigInteger('phonenumber');
    });
}
```

UserController with store
    **UserController.php**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'firstname'=>'required',
                'lastname'=>'required',
                'email'=>'required',
            ]);

            $user=new User([
                $user->firstname=>$request->get('firstname'),
                'lastname'=>$request->get('lastname'),
                'email'=>$request->get('email'),
                'dob'=>$request->get('dob'),
                'address'=>$request->get('address'),
                'phonenumber'=>$request->get('phonenumber')
                ]);
                $user->save();
                return redirect('/users')->with('success','user added');
        }
```

Comment: I do not see nullable as a default on the first name or last name column. nullable is correct, or default it to an empty string. Additionally, if `$request->get('firstname')` is null (no first name is passed in), then null is what will be sent to the database. You can change the default on that to an empty string with `$request->get('firstname', '')`

Comment: I haven't added nullable in the code here, but when I added to 'firstname' it gave me  error for 'lastname'. I am passing the values to the table through form. In that case, should I include nullable to every column??

Comment: Correct, add nullable to any column that can have an empty value.

Comment: Also, `$user->firstname=>$request->get('firstname'),` should not have `$user` as the array key

Comment: If I include nullable, for columns and when I enter data through form for these fields 'null' values are displayed in the table.

Comment: are you sure you have (firstname,lastname) in your $fillable in user model?

Comment: No, I have my id and email. Do I need to include all the columns in $fillable??

Comment: It's working now, I have added all the columns. Thank you @OMR

Comment: Thank you :) @aynber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'firstname'=>'required',
            'lastname'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
        ]);

            $user=new User();
            $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
            $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->dob = $request->dob;
            $user->address = $request->address;
            $user->phonenumber = $request->phonenumber;
            $user->save();
            return redirect('/users')->with('success','user added');
    }
```

Also in your model, you have to add this line for mass assignment

```
protected $fillable = ['firstname','lastname','email','dob','address','phonenumber'];
```

You may check out this link for mass assignment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

There is an errors in the code you posted,
Here is the fix:

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'firstname'=>'required',
                'lastname'=>'required',
                'email'=>'required',
            ]);

            $user=new User([
                'firstname' => $request->get('firstname'), // $user->firstname=>$request->get('firstname'),
                'lastname'=> $request->get('lastname'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'dob' => $request->get('dob'),
                'address' => $request->get('address'),
                'phonenumber' => $request->get('phonenumber')
                ]);
                $user->save();
                return redirect('/users')->with('success','user added');
        }
```

also here you are using mass assignment so you should add all used columns to your fillable array in your User model.

Here is [a link on what is mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)